# using EOF instead of feof

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main() {
        FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
        int n, i, num, flag = 0;
        /* open files to write even, odd seperately */
        fp1 = fopen("data.txt", "r");
        fp2 = fopen("even.txt", "w");
        fp3 = fopen("odd.txt", "w");

        fprintf(fp2, "Even Numbers:\n");
        fprintf(fp3, "Odd Numbers:\n");

        /* print even, odd and prime numbers in separate files */
        while (!feof(fp1)) {
                fscanf(fp1, "%d", &num);
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                        fprintf(fp2, "%d ", num);
                } else {
                        if (num > 1) {
                                for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
                                        if (num % i == 0) {
                                                flag = 1;
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        fprintf(fp3, "%d ", num);
                        flag = 0;
                }
        }
        fprintf(fp2, "\n");
        fprintf(fp3, "\n");

        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp3);
        return 0;
  }
```

I want to use EOF instead of feof. I have tried !EOF = fp1 but it doesn't work and gives an error. I just want to replace feof with EOF. can anyone indicate what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?rq=1

Comment: You should check the return status of `fscanf` instead. If the end of file is reached, `fscanf` will return  `EOF`. See the **RETURN VALUE** of [man fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: `EOF` and `feof()` are entirely different things. `feof()` is a _function_ which checks to see if the end-of-file indicator has been set, and `EOF` is a _macro_ for the value returned by some functions when end-of-file has been reached.

Comment: can you please tell me how do I replace with EOF? I am still not getting my answer

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/) because it is, and your code runs into the problems that arise from abusing `feof()`.

Comment: Replace `while (!feof(fp1)) {
                fscanf(fp1, "%d", &num); … }` with `while (fscanf(fp1, "%d", &num) == 1) { … }`.  Note that this behaves sanely even when you type a word instead of a number; it stops processing the (erroneous) data.  It doesn't use EOF; comparing with EOF would not spot the problems with words instead of numbers.

Comment: EOF is an integer value returned by functions like `fgetc()` and `getchar()`. You're not using any of those functions, so you won't see one.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be treating prime numbers differently from odd numbers (yet — but the comments say you should/will be doing so, eventually).  If you do end up treating primes differently, don't forget that 2 is both even and prime.

Answer (score 3):

`fscanf` returns `EOF` when the end-of-file is reached:

> *man fscanf*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int scanf(const char *format, ...);
> int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
> int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The `scanf()` function reads input from the standard input stream `stdin`, `fscanf()` reads input from the stream pointer `stream`, and
>   `sscanf()` reads its input from the character string pointed to by `str`.
>
> [...]
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or
>   even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> **The value `EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
>   `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and `errno` is set
>   to indicate the error.**

A solution would be to read save the return value of `fscanf` in a `int`
variable and check it agains 0 and `EOF`, like this:

If you want to keep using `fscanf`:

```
int ret;
while((ret = fscanf(fp1, "%d, &num)) != EOF)
{
    if(ret == 0)
    {
        // fscanf failed to convert the input
        // let it consume a charatcer and try again.
        getc(fp1);
        continue;
    }

    if(num % 2 == 0)
        ...
}
```

**edit**

Avoid using `feof` to control looping on a file like this `while(!feof(fp)`, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/) for more
information about that.

---

**edit 2**

This was my original idea, but as Jonathan Leffler pointed out in the comments:

> *Jonathan Leffler wrote:*
>
> Your first solution demands a single number per line, which the code in the question does not

He's right, I didn't see that.

> *me from the past*
>
> One option would be to read the input line by line using `fgets` and then use
>   `sscanf` to parse the line:
>
> ```
> char buffer[1024];
>
> while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp1))
> {
>     if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num) != 1)
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Could not read an integer, ignoring line\n");
>         continue;
>     }
>
>     if (num % 2 == 0)
>         ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for the while loop should be the `fscanf()` statement itself. `EOF` is always an integer. See the [manual page for `fscanf()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/fscanf.htm):

> **Return Value**
>
> The fscanf() function returns the number of fields that it successfully converted and assigned. The return value does not include fields that the fscanf() function read but did not assign.
>
> The return value is EOF if an input failure occurs before any conversion, or the number of input items assigned if successful.

And, like everyone else I will refer you to **[Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?rq=1)**. This is essential reading on Stack Overflow for new C programmers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
    int n, i, num, flag = 0, ret;

    /* fopen files */

    while ((ret = fscanf(fp1, "%d", &num)) != EOF) {
        if (ret == 0) {
            getc(fp1);
            continue;
        }
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            fprintf(fp2, "%d ", num);
        }
        /* rest of the loop here */
    }

    /* fclose files */
}
```

If `fscanf()` fails to read a character, but does not return EOF, it can often solve things to `getc()`, to advance the buffer by one character. This method also works when using `getchar()` to advance stdin, after getting user input from `scanf()`.